# Ubuntu 20.04 on Thinkpad t14s gen1 amd mute mic led is not reacting changing mic status

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, thinkpad, indicator-sound

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2

kernel 5.8.0-41-generic
```

My laptop is certified for ubuntu: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202006-27978

### Problem:

There is a Mic mute led indicator on the <kbd>F4</kbd> button.

If I turn the mic on/off (that can be checked in settings as the mic status is changing, see below) the led indicator is not changing its state.

[image: enabling mic]
[image: disabling mic]

I've checked the `alsamixer`:

[image: alsa mixer mode]

Changing the mode of mic mute led is not changing its behaviour (but it's reacting on mode change - it can be constantly on or off, not depending on mic status).

How can I make it work properly?

> PS: On Fedora 33 it worked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not found, but this problem was solved in 22.04.